# CSS linking issues

Tags: php, css

i need some help with linking css to a php file.

This was completed by someone else and now i need to fix it. We have the main css that controls the look and feel of the entire site. The other CSS is just for the accordions page. that needs to be added in.

Current links include:

```
<!-- CSS Linking -->
      <link href="css/template.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
     <link href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template; ?>/css/accord.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

If i remove the ?php echo from the second one it doesn't work, but if i leave it in there the css/template.css doesn't work.

Basically if both are in there are the same time they one doesn't work. Is there are way to resolve this?

Comment: What is the output after the PHP is parsed?

Comment: Add a `;` after `$this->baseurl`.

Comment: @EdCottrell thanks for the suggestion, tired that didn't work...

Comment: what does the href compile to in the browser?

Comment: @JohnConde /css/accord.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" (is that what you are talking about? Sorry unsure what you mean by the output after the php is parsed?

Comment: It doesn't include `/templates`? Are you sure both of those variables are printing out anything?

Comment: @ShanRobertson The href is just the link to the style sheets. Also where do i need to add the /templates?

Comment: Sorry, maybe i misinterpreted? It was my understanding you couldn't get the css file to load at all. Is it loading?

Comment: @ShanRobertson Yes they can both run seperately but if i have them both in there, only the second run will run

Comment: Turn on error reports  - `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` and view your page source to see if there are any errors.

Comment: @Darren Where do i add that code?

Comment: At the top of your page inside `<?php ?>` tags

Comment: @Darren says Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) for /css/template.css

Comment: What happens when you try the full path to the `css/template.css` file?

Comment: Thats funny i just tried that, got the same result. went from domain.com/templates/css/template.css and still got the second css working only. And the result with the failed load resource is the same.

Comment: @Darren the file is now being located but still now showing at all.

Comment: Can you clarify what `"but still now showing at all"` means ?

Comment: @Darren The style sheet that is running isn't working correcly like on all the other pages. The footer columns and button colours, hovers, etc don't work. If i remove the second linked css all of this works correctly but the accordions css doesn't work.

Comment: So what do you do differently on this page that you don't do on the other pages?

Comment: @Darren footer columns, buttons, hovers, colours etc. Its kinds like they just both don't want to work together to get the page looking nice.

Comment: Either the CSS files aren't being loaded properly, or they are, and the content of one is overwriting the other. Once you determine they're actually loaded properly and the paths are correct, you should post your CSS to the question as it would appear that either the rules for one contradict the other, or the specificity is causing problems.

Comment: @j08691 The original creator added a whole lot of body elements that have been taking over from the other code. Thank you this has resolved the issue and both are now working together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was that in the css of the second file there was an element of code that was overwriting the other file. The people had a body element. This has been removed and now both working together well.